# how to download all the pdf inside a class python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf

I have around 900 pages and each page contains 10 buttons (each button has pdf). I want to download all the pdf's - the program should browse to all the pages and download the pdfs one by one.
in this some of the pdf's (randomly) are not downloading (the code is going till end page) but some pdf randomly from some pages are not downloading
around 4521 pdf are downloading out of 9000 pdf

Code only searching for .pdf but my href does not have .pdf page_no (1 to 900).

```
https://bidplus.gem.gov.in/bidlists?bidlists&page_no=3
```

This is the website and below is the link:

BID NO: GEM/2021/B/1804626

below is the my code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

end_number = 900
current_page = 1
pdf_links = {}
path = '<your path>'

with requests.Session() as s:
    while True:
        r = s.get(f'https://bidplus.gem.gov.in/bidlists?bidlists&page_no={current_page}')
        soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
        for i in soup.select('.bid_no > a'):
            pdf_links[i.text.strip().replace('/', '_')] = 'https://bidplus.gem.gov.in' + i['href']
        #print(pdf_links)
        if current_page == 1:
            num_pages = int(soup.select_one('.pagination li:last-of-type > a')['data-ci-pagination-page'])
            print(num_pages)
        if current_page == num_pages or current_page > end_number:
            break
        current_page+=1
    
for k,v in pdf_links.items():
    with open(f'{path}/{k}.pdf', 'wb') as f:
        r = s.get(v)
        f.write(r.content)
```

Comment: When your URL refers to a file, you should consider streaming the response. Also, you're using the session reference (*s*) after it's been closed. Your *for* loop should be indented

Comment: @JCaesar pls answer it by making the code changes...

Comment: I would but I can't test it due to the fact that that URL isn't responding at the moment (ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT)

Comment: @JCaesar just use proxy site or make code changes i will test mmyself and let u know

Comment: @JCaesar getting syntax error

Answer (score 1):

UNTESTED but demonstrates how files can be streamed using the *requests* module:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor


def writepdf(k, v):
    path = '<YOUR_PATH>'
    with requests.Session() as session:
        with open(f'{path}/{k}.pdf', 'wb') as f:
            with session.get(v, stream=True) as r:
                for data in r.iter_content():
                    f.write(data)

def main():
    with requests.Session() as s:
        current_page = 1
        end_number = 900
        threads = []
        with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
            while current_page <= end_number:
                r = s.get(f'https://bidplus.gem.gov.in/bidlists?bidlists&page_no={current_page}')
                r.raise_for_status()
                soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
                for i in soup.select('.bid_no > a'):
                    k = i.text.strip().replace('/', '_')
                    v = f'https://bidplus.gem.gov.in{i["href"]}'
                    threads.append(executor.submit(writepdf, k, v))
                if current_page == 1:
                    num_pages = int(soup.select_one('.pagination li:last-of-type > a')['data-ci-pagination-page'])
                    end_number = min(end_number, num_pages)
                current_page += 1
            for t in threads:
                t.result()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: File "C:/Users/deepak jain/PycharmProjects/SeleniumTest/DEMO/dd.py", line 16
    (r := s.get(f'https://bidplus.gem.gov.in/bidlists?bidlists&page_no={current_page}')).raise_for_status()
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: That's because your Python version is out of date. You'll need either 3.7+ or change the code so as not to use the walrus operator

Comment: could you pleease update your code (without walrus)

Comment: Done - but you really should consider updating your Python environment

Comment: code is taking too much time 1000 record are taking 1 hr

Comment: Multithreading is very likely to solve your problem. It's not this code that's slow *per se*. The issue will be the rate at which the PDFs can be downloaded

Comment: I've edited the Answer to utilise multithreading. Still untested as unable to reach the specified host

Comment: 1600 RECORDS IN 1 HR

Comment: If that's not fast enough then you'll need to try something else. Start by adding some timing reporting to the writepdf() function. On the basis of your last comment it looks like it's taking just over 2 seconds to download each PDF